# Mongodb text search not working with string Flask

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, flask

I am trying to make text search with Flask.

For one word it works, but when I pass a string with multiple words it doesn't work.

But when I pass that string as hardcoded it works:

Suppose that string is this:

```
str = "SOME TEXT HERE"
```

if I pass it as variable like this:

```
newText= ' '.join(r'\"'+word+r'\"' for word in str.split())
    result = app.data.driver.db[endpoint].find({"$text":{"$search":newText }}, {"score": {"$meta":"textScore"}}).sort([("score", {"$meta": "textScore"})])
```

it doesn't work.

But if I pass it as hardcoded like this:

```
    result = app.data.driver.db[endpoint].find({"$text":{"$search":" \"SOME\" \"TEXT\" \"HERE\" " }}, {"score": {"$meta":"textScore"}}).sort([("score", {"$meta": "textScore"})])
```

It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of variable `newText` are different from the contents in your hardcoded string.

Try removing 'r' during creation of `newText` to generate a string similar to the hardcoded string, as follows:

```
newText= ' '.join('\"'+word+'\"' for word in str.split())
```